# I cannot switch node.js version

Tags: node.js

I am trying to switch my node.js version.

What I did is:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n 10.10.0
```

But I check my current version after I did it by using

```
node -v
```

It always shows

```
v6.14.3
```

I am not sure if I do anything wrong. Any suggestion please?

Comment: Try using `nvm` https://github.com/creationix/nvm#installation

Comment: hmm, what does `where node` return out of curiosity? (but yes, `nvm` is the preferred way to update)

Comment: I just got it! Thank you for your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Intervalia, [try using using NVM (node version manager)](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#install-script)

With nvm, you can very easily do things like:

`nvm install 10.10.0` and it will download that version of node. And then do `nvm use 10.10.0` and then doing `node -v` will return `10.10.0`.

> Here is what happens when I run `nvm list`

[image: node version manager and the ease of use]